# Google App Engine, set entity id to null string

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Ex.

```
Entity(id='', parent=user_key)
```

When I try to create an entity with the null string as the id, Google App Engine interprets it as having no id, and defaults to an automatically generated integer id.

I've also tried creating the key beforehand, and passing it in.

```
key = ndb.Key('User', user_key.id(), 'Entity', '')
Entity(key=key)
```

The same issue occurs.

Is there any way to work around this behavior and use the null string as the entities id?

Edit:

Since everyone seems to be wondering why I would want to do this. Imagine a situation like stackoverflow where a user can upvote and downvote a question. You want the user to only have one vote per question. So it's natural to manually set the id of the vote entity to the key of the question. Combined with a user parent, this ensures that there is one per user per question. The twist here is that I have a special case where a user can have one of this entity that belongs to nothing other than the user. The matter is further complicated by the fact that the key for the entity that it usually belongs to is tied to a user submitted string. So, if I use anything but the null string for this special case, there is a security issue where the special case could collide with another entity.

Comment: how many of these entries are you planning on creating? :P

Comment: The id is only set this way for a specific case of an entity, that should only have 1 per user.

Comment: you'd be better off ignoring the ID's entirely and finding some other way to do it such as ancestor relationships or using get_or_insert

Comment: Given you want only a single explicit ID with a ancestor, then use a known string instead of an INT (like 'MY_SENTINAL_ID' or 'X' ;-) it will never clash unless you do something wrong in your code.  Why use a NULL when any controlled value will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that there is only one entity of this kind per parent entity, set the ID to 1:

Entity(id=1, parent=user_key)

Comment: Will this cause conflicts with automatically generated integer ids?

Comment: The key of a child entity includes keys of all parent entities, so a key created with this ID will not conflict with any other keys.

Answer (score 0):

Id must be unique, so using `null` is not a good idea, because you'll be able to store only one entity. Id must be not `null`, or it will be automatically generated.

Comment: The id is only set this way for a specific case of an entity, that should only have 1 per user.

Comment: Your use case doesn't change the answer. Id must be unique and not null or will be automatically generated. You've to deal with it in other way.